# Is there already a project that syncs video speed to audio beats/volume?

Tags: audio, neural-network, video-processing

Today I saw a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85l961MmY8Y) (found via this [Twitter post](https://twitter.com/xsteenbrugge/status/1188785427295195136?s=20)) where a video seemed to speed up or slow down depending on the volume/beats/other of the music playing. I'm extremely curious about how this was done and was wondering if there's already a GitHub project or something that does this already because otherwise I'll code it. I tried Googling and searching around GitHub for it but came up empty handed.

Does anyone know how to get this effect?

Comment: You could probably achieve this with [Processing](https://processing.org/) and the corresponding sound and video libraries

Comment: Just to clarify, you're interested in video playback speed as controlled by volume (amplitutde) and not looking for the image synthesis?